# What speed are most multiplayer StarCraft II games played at?

Tags: starcraft-2

I just started playing some practice games, and noticed that there are several speed options (Slow, Normal, Fast, etc).  I'd like to get used to the right speed for playing multiplayer, so what do most people play at?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All league games are played on Faster.